# change string to specific date-time format

Tags: r, datetime

in my R-projekt I have to deal with different date formats encoded as strings.
My general format should be `"YYYY-MM-DD;HH:mm:ss"`, so for example: `"2012-12-01;12:00:12"`.

The strings I received are not necessarily on the correct format. Here are some examples and how they should look like after the conversion:

- `"2012-12-01"` => `"2012-12-01;:00:00:00"`
- `"2012-12-01;12:43"` => `"2012-12-01;:12:43:00"`
- `"947-12-01;12:43"` => `"0947-12-01;12:43:00"`
- `"1947-8-1;12:43:00"` => `"1947-08-01;12:43:00"`

As you see, each missing value should be filled with a zero. Is there any way to define a general schema and parse the string at once. S.th. like `function(input = "947-12-01;12:43", aim = "0000-00-00;00:00:00")`

Comment: So you need a format like format = "%Y-%m-%d;%H:%M:%S"?

Comment: Could you please provide reproducible data?

Comment: Look at `strptime()` or the lubridate `ymd()` / `ymd_hms()` families. You will always need to specify the input format in some way because there’s inherent ambiguity in date and time conventions. e.g., R has no way of knowing a priori if `"2012-12-01"` represents December 1 or January 12.

Comment: but is there a way to let R automatically fill in missing values with 0?

Comment: I should add  that  the  final  result  does  not  need  to  be of tiype  posixct,  it should be a string